# Как организовать работу на удаленном сервере с разными версиями Python

Tags: python, pycharm

Обращаюсь к уважаемому сообществу со следующим вопросом. Ранее я задавал вопрос на эту тему, но тогда он был сформирован некорректно. Исправляюсь.

Имеется удаленный сервер (Debian), в которых будут проекты с разными версиями Python. Необходимо решить следующие вопросы:

1. Как настроить среду в Pycharm таким образом, чтобы изменения в коде на
   локальной машине экспортировались на сервер?
2. В проектах будут использоваться разные версии Python. Этот вопрос решается через библиотечку 'Pyenv'. 
   Установкой различных версий Python под проекты. Проблема заключается в следующем кейсе:

   -"Я работаю в проекте, требующем версию Python 3.6. Интерпретатору в Pycharm назначен путь до нужной версии Python. Далее я переключаюсь на иной проект, требующий версию 3.8. А в интерпретаторе указан путь до версии 3.6."

   Как сделать так, чтобы версия Python интерпретатора в Pycharm-e менялась автоматически на версию Python в проекте, как только в терминале перехожу на нужный проект?

Comment: Если переходить, используя `File -> Open Project`, интерпретатор меняется автоматически.

Comment: Для передачи изменений на удалённый сервер есть `Tools -> Deployment`. Хотя я использовал бы `Git` и через `SSH` пуллил бы изменения.